# Receiving PHP Warning on move to Production

Tags: php, hosting

I am moving a client site from my staging VPS to my clients preferred hosting. All of Crafts requirements check out just fine:

PHP Version 7.0.29
MySQL Version   10.2.12-MariaDB-log

However, when going to either admin or main homepage I get the following warning:

`Wrong parameter count for class_alias()`

The file it is pointing to is `/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/LoaderInterface.php(57)`

What am I possibly missing?

My VPS has the following settings:
PHP Version 5.6.36
MySQL Version   5.6.39

Comment: What version of Craft?

Comment: Latest of version 2 (2.6.3016)

Comment: Hrm... Can you enable devMode and share the full stack trace leading up to that error in the original question?

Comment: Hey Brad, here is link to the full stack trace: https://www.dropbox.com/s/exi4a1xclc56ity/PHP%20warning.html?dl=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So Brad tracked down the issue being Twig needs at least PHP 5.2.7 to run. As of 1.34, the minimum requirement was bumped to PHP 5.3.3. Craft bumped up Twig to 1.35 in version 2.6.3001

https://twig.symfony.com/doc/1.x/intro.html

My clients server was actually running 5.3.29. The server default was 7, bumping it up to php 5.4 fixed the site.